# Tensorflow stft does not use gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very simple tensorflow program that computes the spectrogram of a wav file:

```
# load a wav file into audio_data

audio_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(audio_data, dtype=tf.float32)

stft = tf.contrib.signal.stft(audio_data, frame_length=255, frame_step=1)
mag = tf.abs(stft)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    mag = sess.run(mag)
```

The docs for `tf.contrib.signal.stft` say its implemented with GPU-compatible ops, and I see the device placement logs say every op in the program is being placed on my gpu. However, when I run this, my **cpu** is maxed out at 100%, and my **gpu** is completely idle. I've also tried adding an explicit `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` above the stft line, but to no avail. What do I need to do to get this running on my gpu? Could it be a bug with the op? Other gpu ops, such as the convolution ops, seem to work great with my gpu and I can get full 100% usage from it when I use those.

I am on Linux Ubuntu, Tensorflow 1.4.1 (compiled from source), and I am using CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0.